# Responsive nav-items

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar

Ok this is a real challenge and I have searched everyehere! I have created a Bootstrap 4 navigation bar. The navigation bar has nav-items goung right across the navbar. I am wanting the SPACING between each nav item to adapt according to the viewport size-so no items fall outside of view-a bit like here: https://carrabbasatlanticcanada.com/

I have tried setting the padding between the nav items in ems-but this did not do the trick.
I also tried justifying the text but the padding still does not adjust.

Here is the code:

```css
.mynav .myBrand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.navbar {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}


/*link*/

.navbar .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #cda45e;
}


/*link hover color*/

.navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}


/*link focus color*/


/*Nav item spacing*/

.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-right: 9em;
}


/*Hamburger*/

.custom-toggler .fa-solid {
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.custom-toggler .fa-solid:hover {
  width: 80px;
  color: orange;
  margin: 6px 0;
}


/*Dropdown arrow*/

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .3em;
  height: .3em;
  margin: -.3em 0 0 -.1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border: .3em solid;
  border-width: 0 .15em .15em 0;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg)
}


/*Dropdown menu*/

.dropdown-menu #myList a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#navbarNav li a:hover {
  color: #cda45e;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css  /bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mynav " id="navbar_top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand  myBrand pl-xl-5" href="index.html">Web Title</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl" style="width:40px"></i>
              </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#top-content">Top</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--Dropdown Menu Start-links could be to pdf, image or webpage-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#about-us" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      About
                     </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <div class="d-lg-flex align-items-start justify-content-start" id="myList">
              <div>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#lunch"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;LUNCH MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#dinner"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;EVENING MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;DESSERT MENU</a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#drinks"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;DRINKS MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#BOOK"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;BOOK A TABLE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Dropdown Menu End-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Clients</a>
          </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give fixed values it won't change according to screen size. Using `em` which is dependent on `font-size` won't work if the `font-size` isn't changing.
You need to create a flex-row and have the elements spaced-around you can read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink).

Working example bellow.

```css
.mynav .myBrand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.navbar {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}


/*link*/

.navbar .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #cda45e;
}


/*link hover color*/

.navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}


/*link focus color*/


/*Nav item spacing*/
/*
.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-right: 9em;
}
*/

/*Hamburger*/

.custom-toggler .fa-solid {
  width: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.custom-toggler .fa-solid:hover {
  width: 80px;
  color: orange;
  margin: 6px 0;
}


/*Dropdown arrow*/

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .3em;
  height: .3em;
  margin: -.3em 0 0 -.1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border: .3em solid;
  border-width: 0 .15em .15em 0;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg)
}


/*Dropdown menu*/

.dropdown-menu #myList a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#navbarNav li a:hover {
  color: #cda45e;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mynav " id="navbar_top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand  myBrand pl-xl-5" href="index.html">Web Title</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl" style="width:40px"></i>
              </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <!-- Change the ul bellow -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-around flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#top-content">Top</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--Dropdown Menu Start-links could be to pdf, image or webpage-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#about-us" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      About
                     </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <div class="d-lg-flex align-items-start justify-content-start" id="myList">
              <div>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#lunch"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;LUNCH MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#dinner"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;EVENING MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;DESSERT MENU</a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#drinks"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;DRINKS MENU</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item pb-3" href="#BOOK"><img src="assets/images/img1.jpg" alt="menu image">&nbsp;BOOK A TABLE</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Dropdown Menu End-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">Clients</a>
          </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
</nav>
```